# Keycloak-admin-client always returns null in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I using the keycloak admin client in my app

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in my code I have:

```
package br.com.fabioebner.api.serivce;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmResource;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.ClientRepresentation;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.RealmRepresentation;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class KeycloakService {
    private final RealmRepresentation realm;
    private final Keycloak keycloak;

    public KeycloakService() {
        this.keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
                "https://myIp/auth/",
                "master",
                "admin",
                "password",
                "admin-cli");
        this.realm = keycloak.realm("myRealm").toRepresentation();
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void addUser(){
        List<UserRepresentation> users = realm.getUsers();
        users.forEach(user -> {
            log.debug(user.getUsername());
        });
    }
}
```

Why the `realm.getUsers()` always returns null??

if I put `realm.getClients()` returns null too, but I have users and clients in my realm "myRealm".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the users from the `Realm` *representation*

```
this.realm = keycloak.realm("myRealm").toRepresentation()
```

Tried to get them from the `Realm` instead, namely:

```
UsersResource usersResource = keycloak.realm("myRealm").users();
...
List<UserRepresentation> users = usersResource.list();     
users.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u.getUsername()));
```